# I receive {"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.","data":{"status":401}} when trying to retrieve a private post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Trying to retrieve a post using the REST API:

http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/605.

I am authenticated as administrator and the post was published my me. I have all the administrator rights assigned. I can retrieve non-private posts but as soon as I mark them private I get an error as a response

```
{"code":"rest_forbidden","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to allow retrieval of private posts ?

-- Edit: I am authenticated via JWT but my response returns all public posts and none of the private ones

```
if (await client.IsValidJWToken())
                {                  
                    var queryBuilder = new PostsQueryBuilder();
                    queryBuilder.PerPage = 8;
                    queryBuilder.Page = 1;
                    queryBuilder.Embed = true;
                    //queryBuilder.Categories = new int[] { category };
                    queryBuilder.Statuses = new Status[] { };

                    try
                    {
                        var response = await client.Posts.Query(queryBuilder);
                        var r = response;

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        var m = e.Message;

                    }
```

Comment: Without seeing how exactly you're trying to retrieve the post we can't be of much help so please provide more details (eg. a [minimal, reproducible example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice.)

Comment: This is probably a permission problem. Do you know how to use the debugger? It can show you exactly why the request is rejected. I don't think you need to write code. But, find exactly what permission is missing.

Comment: "I am authenticated as administrator" - being logged in to the site does not automatically log you in to the REST API endpoint. And by default, viewing private posts requires [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) - did you authenticate your request?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, I edited the  original post to add the code. I can retrieve all public posts but the private ones don't show up in the list. The same thing happens even if I don't use the query builder.

Comment: @Orbiter, "don't show up in the list" - if you are retrieving a list of posts, you need to explicitly specify the post status(es) except if you're only retrieving posts that are published, in addition to being authenticated. So for example, one may request `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=publish,draft`. Have you tried setting the status(es)?

Comment: "in addition to being authenticated" - when requesting **draft** posts (and posts having certain status)

Comment: @SallyCJ  Yes. I get "status forbidden" for anything other than when the status requested is set to "published"
 ```{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): status","data":{"status":400,"params":{"status":"Status is forbidden."}}}```

Comment: Sorry @Orbiter, I actually meant to say "private" and not "draft", but the same restriction also does apply to draft posts. So I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but it could happen because either the request isn't authenticated or that the associated user does not have permissions to access private posts. Double-check the authentication (or that the request does include the proper authentication data) and also the permissions.

Comment: You can also try creating a new post via the REST API and see if it succeeded. If yes, then maybe it's a permission issue. (Yes I know you said "administrator", but who knows..)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the expected behavior [at least I can confirm the same thing on my sites]. You'll probably have to create your own route to access the private posts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you know what's the fastest way to do that? I would also be able to delete and update the private posts